# Pjsip how to login in to sip account

Tags: ios, pjsip, pjsua2

I am working on pjsip app for iOS. But I am facing trouble to login into pjsip account after relaunching app. If anyone has any idea about it then please help.

Comment: put your code and logs that where you got trouble? what error did you get? Explain the error in your question.

Comment: I have only registration code. So basically I wants to know if there is any method available to login? because I am not able to find it.

Comment: Use Registration as a login. Because you can make a call after successful registration.

Comment: @NandhaKumar Thanks :)

Comment: @NandhaKumar I have one more question, do you know how to call Pjsua call handler methods in different class